# Luwak/Lucene vs Solr: TrieDateField range query

Tags: solr, lucene

For our system, we have a solr scheme defined with the basic TrieDateField fieldType, which has precisionStep=6 as well as stored/indexed/docvalues all equal to true. We also have a custom query parser which will take a query like 'date > 2012-02-10T13:19:11Z' and turn it into a range query (in lucene syntax it would look something like date:{1328879951000 TO *], but under the hoods it's just calling the getRangeQuery method on a TrieDateField object).

When running the query date > 2012-02-10T13:19:11Z in solr, I will correctly get back documents with a date field of 2014-05-11T12:00:00Z. However, when matching using luwak, the above query matches against nothing. In fact, the only query that works is with strict equality. However, if i change the precisionStep in the scheme for tdate to be either 0 or a high number (above say 32), all range queries work as expected.

Is there a reason range queries are matching only with less indexed ranges (higher precisionStep)? Why is it different between solr and luwak, if they're using the same schema and same query parser?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone comes across this later (though this was probably a niche question considering no answers and I'm using a deprecated field type), I was indexing the the date without a specified precisionStep, while the query DID have a precisionStep.

When building the luwak document, I did:

```
InputDocument doc = InputDocument.builder("doc1")
    .addField("date", iso_date_string, customAnalyzer).build();
```

When I needed to do something akin to:

```
FieldType ft = new FieldType();
ft.setNumericType(FieldType.LegacyNumericType.LONG);
ft.setNumericPrecisionStep(6);
ft.setStored(false);
ft.setIndexOptions(IndexOptions.DOCS_AND_FREQS_AND_POSITIONS_AND_OFFSETS);
LegacyLongFiled field = ("date", iso_date_as_long, ft);
builder.addField(field);
```

Where iso_date_as_long is the given iso_date_string converted to date with JodaTime, converted back to string with DateTools.dateToString, and then converted to a long again with DateTools.stringToTime.

Comment: I'm query about the concept of "the query DID have a precisionStep"  Are you saying that ultimately the range query had arguments that were converted to a NumericType that had a Precision step of 6?